# Shortly URL profile Page

Tags: php

I want to ask you about profile page url of twitter/facebook.
Example :

```
twitter.com/stackoverflow 

facebook.com/stackoverflow
```

Now I want to set in my web page,
example :

```
abc.com/nagabotak
```

I've tried to search the tutorial in stackoverflow, but I miss something that I don't understand the concept.

I have a profiles.php page.
Current if I want to open the profile page, I must using `abc.com/profile.php?user=nagabotak`

So what I want to do is short the url to be `abc.com/nagabotak`

Comment: It's called "pretty URLs" and is realized by *URL rewriting*. There are two keywords you can use for further research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It calls URL rewrite.

check for more info:

http://www.cyberdesignz.com/blog/website-design/url-rewriting-top-5-ways-of-php-url-rewriting/
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

create a htaccess with the rewrite rule, read the links and you will find it how to fix it =)

edit

here is my rewrite rule, I rewrite to the index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Don't forget if you work with nginx, nginx doesn't use .htaccess.

If you done that you have to create the routs that you want, like profile/name